# Add vector of rational numbers to edges of a graph in R

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I wanted to add rational/ fractional numbers to edges of a graph in R (I'm using igraph)
I tried as follows:

```
xval=0.2
frvals<-runif(50,max=xval)

g<-graph.full(n=50,directed = TRUE)
adj<-get.adjacency(g,sparse = FALSE)

g<-add.edges(g,frvals)
```

> Error in .Call("R_igraph_add_edges", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph, edges)
>   -  :    At type_indexededgelist.c:272 : cannot add edges, Invalid vertex id

```
g <- make_empty_graph(n = 50) %>%
    add_edges(runif(50, 0,xval))
```

But this is working for real numbers

```
g <- make_empty_graph(n = 50) %>%
    add_edges(ceiling(runif(50, 0,xval)))
E(g)[[]]
plot(g)
```

Comment: I (we?)  cannot read your mind to determine what "add rational/ fractional numbers to a graph" actually means to you.

Comment: @42- values like 0.125, 0.3658,1.54568 and so on